# startx and system-wide default gnome session

Tags: gnome, default, session

I get into X by startx (not lightdm).

How can I define the default gnome session (gnome-classic instead of 2d/3d) system-wide for all users?

Comment: Are you asking two question here? How to fix for not having to use `startx` and setting `gnome-classic` as default session?

Comment: I got this error: update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/gnome-session-fallback for x-session-manager not registered, not setting. Any ideas?

Comment: I still got the same error. Looks like gnome-session-fallback isn't registered. If I run this: update-alternatives --list x-session-manager I only get 1 result: /usr/bin/gnome-session From the help menu I'm seeing install with these options: --install <link> <name> <path> <priority> Thought maybe I could install gnome-session-fallback with this command: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-session-fallback gnome-session-fallback /usr/bin/x-session-manager 1 But I get errors after: > update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/x-session-manager to provide /usr/bin/gnome-session-fallback (g

Answer (score 1):

The thing that gets run is `x-session-manager`, and this is managed through the alternatives system.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set x-session-manager /usr/bin/gnome-session-fallback
```