# Change desktop environment from terminal in Crouton in chromebook?

Tags: command-line, gnome, desktop-environments, chromebook

I have installed Crouton on my chromebook, with the standard unity desktop(Ubuntu 12.02).

However, I wish to use the Gnome 3 desktop environment. I cannot however install gnome-shell, since it requires me to change the DE from the login screen. Since I log in from the shell of chrome os, this isn't possible.

If I have gnome-shell installed, how can I change the desktop environment from inside Ubuntu, with Unity DE?

Comment: I know this question was posted 4 almost 5 years ago and not sure if it will work but maybe `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`?

Answer (score 0):

Install GNOME Shell normally as you would (ignore the change DE at login screen bit).
I assume so far you logged on using the `startx` command. So once you installed GNOME 3, try logging on using `gnome-shell` (or try `gnome-session` if that doesn't work).

PS: You might also want to look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180827/startx-and-system-wide-default-gnome-session), maybe it will be helpful to you.